# Route to URL in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, routes

I am creating an application which has user profiles. If a user decides to delete their profile (by clicking "Delete Profile" button), it should send a DELETE request to my backend server, then route the user to a "/about" page of my application. The code structure I have is below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
    this.deleteProfile = this.deleteProfile.bind(this);
  }

  deleteProfile() {
     // props contains all the necessary information to construct the request
     // send request to backend server to delete the profile
     // route to /about page
  }

  render() {

    return (
       <button onClick={this.deleteProfile}>Delete Profile</button>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

I haven't been able to find a solution on how to route the user to a URL after they click the Delete Button. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What router are you using?

Comment: I'm just using default Django routing (through urlpatterns). The answer below did what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be abe to make use of the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
  deleteProfile() {
     // props contains all the necessary information to construct the request
     const { data, url } = this.props
     
     // ES6 and asuming you want to pass the id of in the req body
     // data should looks like an obj ->  { id : 'im_id000x' }

     const body = { ...data } 
     const headers = new Headers()
     const deleteURL = 'mydomain.net/profile_image' // it should have http:// or https://
     const redirectURL = 'https://google.de'

     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')

     // Assuming the API requires a DELETE method
     const config = { method: 'DELETE', headers, body: JSON.stringify(body), redirect: 'follow' }


     // Send request to backend server to delete the profile
     fetch(`deleteURL`, config)
         .then(res => res.json())  // assuming the server response is a JSON
         .then(parsedRes => console.log(parsedRes))
         .then(() => {

            // route to /about page
            window.location.href = `${redirectURL}`

         })
         .catch(err => console.error(err.message ? err.message : err))
  }
```